# How do I set google stackdriver to respect logging severity from kubernetes?

Tags: go, logging, kubernetes, stackdriver

I deployed a go application in google cloud using kubernetes which automatically logs to google stackdriver. Oddly, all log statements are being tagged with severity "ERROR"

For example:

```
log.Println("This should have log level info")
```

will be tagged as an error.

[Their docs say](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/logging) "Severities: By default, logs written to the standard output are on the INFO level and logs written to the standard error are on the ERROR level."

Anyone know what could be wrong with my setup?

Comment: are you using GKE or did you create your own cluster manually within Compute Engine?

Comment: @PatrickW Do you have any solutions for GKE ?

Comment: fluentd in GKE has the default behavior of marking logs from stdout as INFO and stderr as ERROR. From memory, Go is sending all logs to stderr. The fluentd agent in GKE can't be modified, so your two options are to install your own fluentd and remove Google's or you need to modify your code to output non errors to stdout

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this logging package: [github.com/teltech/logger](https://github.com/teltech/logger), with an accompanying [blog post](https://dev.to/hitman666/go-logger-with-kubernetes-stackdriver-format-compatibility-65k). It will output your logs in a JSON format, including the severity, that is readable by the Stackdriver Fluentd agent.